# Почему добавление индекса mysql не ускоряет работу

Tags: sql, index

Работаю в программе MySQL Workbench. Движок InnoDB.

Есть бд `shop` и таблица товаров `product` на 4 тыс. записей.
Хочу увеличить скорость выполнения запроса (скорость доступа).

Делаю два подряд запроса:

```
SELECT * FROM  shop.product WHERE price = 1465;

SELECT * FROM  shop.product WHERE price = 1465;
```

Проверяю, скорость доступа 2-го запроса должна быть 0.00 сек, потому что "база запоминает предыдущие запросы". У меня же почему то оба запроса +/- 0,00055 сек.

И потом: 
добавляю индекс к поисковому полю price

```
ALTER TABLE `shop`.`product` 
ADD INDEX `price_index` USING BTREE (`price`) VISIBLE;
;
```

И скорость выполнения предыдущего запроса остается такой же, вроде индекс и не добавляли.

Должно получаться:

(повторный запрос)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(после добавления индекса)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается (при повторном запросе либо после добавления индекса):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как можно что-то измерить на 4-х тысячах записей? Создайте 4 миллиона.

Comment: индексы в мускуле и так б-деревья. лучше покажите create-table самой таблицы.

Comment: 0.00055 секунд? Полмиллисекунды на запрос? И для вас это слишком много???

Comment: @andreymal это у него время исполнения запросов отличается на 0.00055 секунд

Comment: @Igor тогда это абсолютно бесполезное число)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отладка запросов на использование индексов производится через добавление EXPLAIN перед запросами. А сейчас ты сравниваешь теплое с мягким.

Попробуй начать с простых статей

1. https://habr.com/post/31129/
2. https://habr.com/post/211022/

Ну и потом зарывайся в официальный мануал с головой